# Add certificates to global Java truststore in code (programatically)

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, cacerts

I have a Kubernetes Deployment of my Spring Boot application where I used to update global Java `cacerts` using `keytool` at the bootstrap:

```bash
keytool -noprompt -import -trustcacerts -cacerts -alias $ALIAS -storepass $PASSWORD
```

However, I need to make the container immutable using the `readOnlyRootFilesystem: true` in the `securityContext` of the image in my Deployment. Therefore, I cannot update the `cacert` like that with additional certificates to be trusted.

Additional certificates that should be trusted are provided as environment variable `CERTS`.

I assume that the only proper way would be to do this programmatically, for example during `@PostConstruct` in the Spring Boot component.

I was looking into some examples how to set the global truststore in code, but all of them refer to update the `cacerts` and then save it to filesystem, which does not work for me.

Some examples use `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", fileName);`, but this does not work either on the read-only filesystem, where I cannot update file.

Another examples suggest to use `X509TrustManager`, but if I understood correctly, this does not work globally.

Is there any way in Java or Spring Boot to update global truststore in general programmatically so every operation in the code will use and I do not have to implement something like `TrustManager` to every connection? My goal is to have it imported at the begging (similar like it is done using shell and `keytool`). Without touching the filesystem, as it is read-only.

Comment: I have solved this previously by creating a Docker image of your current FROM (eg Alpine) but with the certs added - see the accepted answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231714/how-to-add-trusted-root-ca-to-docker-alpine. Then use that image as your new FROM

Comment: I cannot use this as solution because the certificates are unknown during building image. Certificates are defined as variable and must be loaded during runtime.